# scikitlearn remove less frequent categorical classes

Tags: machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I'm doing a classification task where the number of distinct classes are 1500. From these, I would like to remove those classes (and corresponding record) whose frequency is less than 10.

I can write a function something like this:

```
code_freq_hash = {}
for code in y:
    code_freq_hash.setdefault(code, 0)
    code_freq_hash[code] += 1
```

to get the frequency for each class and then remove corresponding records.
However, I'm wondering whether there is an inbuilt function to do this in scikit learn or keras

Comment: Is your data set a Pandas dataframe or a numpy array? Would a pandas/numpy based solution  work?

Comment: numpy solution will work

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample solution using numpy and pandas.

---

Creating a data set with two features and a one `class` column

```
data = np.hstack((np.array(np.random.randn(20,2)), np.random.choice(np.arange(20), (20,1))))
```

## Numpy

```
val, count = np.unique(data[:,-1], return_counts=True)
val[count>2]
out = data[np.isin(data[:, -1], val[np.isin(val, val[count>2])])] # replace 2 with 10 for your problem
```

## Pandas

Converting the dataset (numpy array) to a pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# renamming the last column to the name "class"
df.rename(columns={ df.columns[-1]: "class" }, inplace=True)

    0                  1    class
0   0.542154    -0.434981   3.0
1   1.513857    -0.606722   17.0
2   0.372834    -0.120914   0.0
3   -1.357369   1.575805    5.0
4   0.547217    0.719883    4.0
5   0.818016    -0.243919   9.0
6   -0.400552   0.066519    19.0
7   0.463596    1.020041    6.0
8   0.850465    -0.814260   14.0
9   1.693060    0.186741    17.0
10  -0.287775   -0.190247   3.0
11  -0.390932   -0.418964   6.0
12  0.209542    0.797151    5.0
13  0.126585    -0.345196   5.0
14  -0.151729   -1.260708   4.0
15  -1.042408   1.050194    6.0
16  -0.221668   1.763742    5.0
17  -0.045617   1.159383    5.0
18  1.452508    -0.785115   5.0
19  2.125601    1.745009    2.0
```

Counting the occurrences and filter only the classes that occur more than twice (set 2 to 10 in your case)

```
d = df.loc[df['class'].isin(df['class'].value_counts().index[df['class'].value_counts() > 2])]
```

You can obtain the numpy array as `d.values`

```
array([[-1.35736852,  1.57580524,  5.        ],
       [ 0.46359614,  1.02004142,  6.        ],
       [-0.39093188, -0.41896435,  6.        ],
       [ 0.20954221,  0.79715056,  5.        ],
       [ 0.12658469, -0.34519613,  5.        ],
       [-1.04240815,  1.05019427,  6.        ],
       [-0.2216682 ,  1.76374209,  5.        ],
       [-0.0456175 ,  1.15938322,  5.        ],
       [ 1.45250806, -0.78511526,  5.        ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be the following code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
unique, appearances = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
code_freq_hash = [(unique[i], appearances[i]) for i in range(len(unique)) if appearances[i] >= 10]
```

Even more elegant, as stated below, `relevant_labels = unique[appearances >= 10]`

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct solution for this in Sklearn but as you mentioned it could be achieved by custom functions.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'labels': np.random.randint(0,10,size=50000),
                  'input': np.random.choice(['sample text 1','sample text 1'],size=50000)})
threshold = 5000

labels_df=df.labels.value_counts()
filtered_labels = labels_df[labels_df>threshold].index

new_df = df.loc[df['labels'].isin(filtered_labels),:]
new_df.shape
#(25290, 2)
```